# How to make dynamic drop down in php?

Tags: codeigniter

I want to make a dynamic drop down in CI.I had done it in CI by directly passing the values from model With its design by concatenation the html.. But now i want it without the html i.e. the function just only should return the array ...
 my before function was something like this...

```
function category() {
        $sql = $this->db->query("select * from ss_category where parent_id='0'");
         $result = $sql->result();
         //print_r($result);die();
         $output = array();
         foreach ($result as $ra) {
             $output=$this->get_child($ra->cat_id);
                    }
        //print_r($output);die();
        return $output;
    }

    function get_child($parent_id) {
        //echo "select * from ss_category where parent_id=" . $parent_id;
        $sql = $this->db->query("select * from ss_category where parent_id=" . $parent_id);
        $r = $sql->result();

        if (!empty($r)) {
            foreach ($r as $s) {
                    $this->get_child($s->cat_id);
            }
            //print_r($child);
         }
         //print_r($r);
     }
```

I want to make drop down something like this..

```
-parent 1
       -child 1
           -subchild 1
       -child 2
       -child 3
          -subchild 1
    -parent 2
      -child 1
```

My table structure is like this..

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| cat_id category_name cat_slug     parent_id level description |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| 1      Elecotronics  Electronics  1               description |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: you are going to need nested `foreach` :) 3x, edit your post and add table structures, thanks.

Comment: How is `subchild` defined? Please fill two more rows in table that represent your tree structure (subchild 1, child 2), thanks.

Comment: Dear Kyslik i want to make the drop down in which the parent may have any number of child and the child may also be a parent if it has child i.e.subchild...

Answer (score 0):

```
function parent_sort($categories)
{
    foreach($categories as $item)
        $childs[$item->parent_id][] = $item;

    foreach($categories as $item) 
        if (isset($childs[$item->category_id]))
            $item->childs = $childs[$item->category_id];

    return $childs[0];
}
```